# rangevalidator rejects wrong values and makes my submit button unresponsive

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a form with a range validator:

```
<label class="required" for="price">price</label>
<input runat="server" id="price" name="price" type="text"  required="required"/>
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="price" ErrorMessage="Must be between 0 and 15,000" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="15000"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

but it rejects values such as '22' and '5' but accepts values '0' and '15,000'. On top of that, it makes my form's submit button unresponsive for all inputs. Why isn't the range validator working?

Edit: Here's the form button

and the submit function that doesn't seem to fire off when I have the rangevalidator. If I remove the rangevalidator, this code executes:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                formInputs.Visible = false;
                emailNotification.Visible = true;

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(emailField.Value);
                mail.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@gmail.com");
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Subject = "Your Form has been submitted";
                mail.Body += "Location: ";
                mail.Body += location.SelectedValue + "<br>";
                mail.Body += " address: ";
                mail.Body += address.Value + "<br>";

                mail.Body += "price: " + price.Value + "<br>";
                mail.Body += "Date submitted: " + todaysDate.Value + "<br>";
                if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
                {

                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(filename)));
                }
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailsetting"]);
                smtp.Send(mail);   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give Type="Integer" in the validator, because you are not giving the type. It might be taking type as string that is why its is not validating as expected.

The validator you have will be modified like this

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="price" ErrorMessage="Must be between 0 and 15,000" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="15000"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: That solved the first problem, but for some reason, it still renders my submit button unresponsive.

Comment: Could you post the code which is in the event of button that goes unresponsive

Comment: Just comment the last statement smtp.Send(mail); I think that could be cause of unresponsiveness of page and also put your code in try catch block

Comment: Remove/Comment all the control from button event and try

Comment: Still unresponsive when I remove the onclick event and the function code. But when I removed the rangevalidator it became responsive again.

Comment: I checked the code it is working perfectly on my machine. Please put the html including button